# How to best encrypt http traffic between frontent (VPS/AWS) and remote backend?

Tags: ssl, openvpn, stunnel

I have a couple of frontend servers running on AWS (running pound for SSL termination and Varnish for caching).  My backend is at a remote location (not on AWS).

I am looking for the best/fastest way to securely connect AWS with my backend.

I assume the best option would be to setup OpenVPN (but this would also require quite a bit of work/configuration).

Would stunnel be sufficient for this particular situation?  Or does anybody have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume the best option would be to setup OpenVPN (but this would
>   also require quite a bit of work/configuration).

*Any* sufficiently-secure encryption system requires work/configuration.

That said, I prefer IPSec over OpenVPN for "static" host-to-host links. Configure it in transport mode and IP headers will remain intact, thereby sparing you the work of having to figure out how to route things through a tunnel.